# What does this symbol mean on Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

Suddenly, I am seeing something very strange on my Xcode.

[image]

I realize that is a static analyzer to help me know where memory leaks can happen but I want to know now how to get rid of this and without changing my code. I mean., what configuration, I can change in xCode to remove that symbol as it wasn't there just minutes ago.

Comment: Analyze: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-source_editor/chapters/Analyze.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you have 72 "static analyzer warnings". The Xcode static analyzer parses your source code and tries to find things that you wouldn't want to happen at runtime (for example never releasing some object to reclaim its memory).

You can find a lot more about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-source_editor/chapters/Analyze.html).

Comment: Thanks, I thought I read about it but then I totally forget. You saved my day!

Comment: Can you please tell me how to remove that from now. I will have to update the code later.